# exporting products as csv then importing them into shopify

Tags: php, database, csv, e-commerce, shopify

I am looking to transfer about 4000 from an older e-commerce platform into shopify.

I have exported some of the products as a csv file and have been looking into how to upload them into shopify but I have come across a rather large problem early on: The csv file downlaoded does not contain the images or a permalink to the image.

One of my old lecturers once told me that he wrote a php script that did a similar thing with emails on a database so I was wondering if you could do this with products on an e-commerce site?

Any information on how to go about doing this would be great, the idea of making a script that does this seems pretty cool and I have noticed that shopify seems to have ready made apps for importing products from Magent and Wordpress.

Here is one of the lines of data in the csv

Harken  Winches Harken          Winches Harken              1       HB0011  WINCH HARKEN ALUMINIUM 1SP  Description 0.7

B6
Gear Ratio: 1:1
Power Ratio: 8.4:1
Fastener Circle: 65mm
Fasteners: 6 x 6mm

B6A 208.564 0   HB0011  1.1 B8A 307.6825    0   HB0014  0
Harken  Winches Harken          Winches Harken              1       HBR3STA WINCH HARKEN  3SPEED STA RADIAL Description 11.7

60.3STA
Drum: 120mm
Base: 236mm
Height: 246mm
Weight: 11.7kg
Fastener circle: 204mm
Gear Ratio 1: 2.20
Gear Ratio 2: 4.80
Gear Ratio 3: 14.40
Power Ratio 1: 9.20
Power Ratio 2: 20.30
Power Ratio 3: 61.00

60.3STA 7183.4058   0   HBR60.3STA  11.7    70.3STA 9893.3115   0   HBR70.3STA  12.8    80.3STA 14834.9199  0   HBR80.3STA  22.7

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Sorry I have tried the standard shopify import method like this one 

http://support.shopify.com/customer/portal/articles/75422-can-i-bulk-import-many-products-at-once-#admin1 

But it does not work which is kind of why I wondered if there was some way of doing it with a script so that I could give that a go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Shopify, but you have to format your CSV file in the way Shopify expects it.

See this article on [Common Product CSV Import Problems](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/import-export/common-import-issues). There are several example files in there as well.

The images will be more difficult. You'll need to download from your current e-commerce host, then [upload them in bulk to Shopify](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/productivity-tools/bulk-editing-products).

Once the images are uploaded you'll either need to reassign them to the products on a product-by-product basis in Shopify, or determine their URL path on Shopify and add that URL to your CSV file before uploading.